# Laravel 5.6 ajax request returns HttpException

Tags: ajax, laravel

I cant get pass this one, im try to do ajax request in laravel and i cant get pass this error:

```
{message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}
```

What does this mean exactly ? **CSRF-TOKEN** token error or ?

ajax request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

$("#send").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var id = 5;

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{url("fly")}}',
            type:'POST',
            data:{id:id},
            success:function(data){
                console.log('Yes' + data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you show the entire error? It seems there is more to this json.

Comment: Yes here it is: 

```message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}
exception
:
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"
file
:
"/var/www/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php"
line
:
203
message```

Comment: @Edo.can you post your routes

Comment: Yes: 

```Route::resource('device','DevicesController');
Route::post('fly','DevicesController@store');```

Comment: @Edo.can you your controller method

Comment: I have included Request on top, 

   ```public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->all();
        return $data;
    }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with CSRF token

You have added CSRf token in ajax Header but in meta you have not specified it.
Add crsf meta in your layout file

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

if You check your Browser network console then you will see 419 error if you are csrf token is not passing properly

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/fly
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 419 unknown status
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

updated header as below since your header token is not set in on document ready nor in on click send

```
$("#send").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var id = 5;

        $.ajax({
headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
            url: '{{url("fly")}}',
            type:'POST',
            data:{id:id},
            success:function(data){
                console.log('Yes' + data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: @Edo check in your browser console status code and also check view page sourve actually crsf token in meta is showing

Comment: When i view the page source i can see the token: 
    ```<meta name="csrf-token" content="ZCGzgdxDQzm47x50P2RVb09MxWJHfjdkfsdfhjshiNJLK">```

Also in the console there is no csrf error

Comment: @yes that means token issue and check my updated answer

Comment: Okay, i check it how can i solve the issue then ? I have already the meta in the master layout.

Comment: @Edo .Make sure you have extended master layout in this page

Comment: I have done that, but i have also the script section inside this layout that is extending the master

Comment: Now i got 500 error, very close to the solution! `"UnexpectedValueException"`

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem.give permsiion to stoage folder 777

Comment: Are you sure about this ?

Comment: @Edo i think so .'

Comment: I got `Yes[object Object]` now how to return the value directly ?

Comment: try using console.log(data); instead of console.log('Yes' + data);

Comment: But the ajax request is working and sending back data! Boom! Thank you @iCoders. I just needed the token inside the $.ajax. You got some votes and the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below CSRF field within the form tag will solve the issue:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Answer (score -1):

I already told you yesterday do this:

```
$("#send").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var id = 5;

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{url("fly")}}',
        type:'POST',
        data:{'id':id,'_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        success:function(data){
            console.log('Yes' + data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: To send the token in the data ?

Comment: Yup. Go ahead and remove ajaxSetup. Change `route::post` to `route::any` and check now.

Comment: I got an syntax error here: `,'_token': {{ csrf_token() }}},`

Comment: Check answer again.